# Display users local zone abbreviation

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I was trying to use `z` or `zz` in format to display the timezone at the end of the string and found that it's deprecated. `Z` and `ZZ` work to display `-0700`, but instead I want it to show `PDT`.

I got `moment-timezone` and the data file, but I can't figure out how to use it to determine the client's local time zone and display something like:

> 2014-05-30T22:56:23.967 PDT

instead of:

> 2014-05-30T22:56:23.967

Is it possible to use `moment-timezone` to determine EST, CST, MST, PST, etc?

Comment: My understanding of the (very minimal) [*documentation*](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) is that it's used for setting the timezone of an output string, not formatting the string, e.g. `m.tz("America/Toronto").format(); // "2013-11-18T11:55:00-05:00"`. There are a number of [utilities](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect) that attempt go guess a users timezone based on the timezone offset and whether daylight saving is observed. However they seem to work using the [*IANA timezone values*](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), not "civil" (ambiguous) values like EST.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As of moment-timezone 0.1.0, you can use the [formatting additions](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/) to get the abbreviation of a *specific* time zone:

```
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('z');  // PST or PDT
```

As of version 0.5.0, you can now [guess the user's *local* time zone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/), which when combined with the above technique, allows you to do the following:

```
moment().tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('z');
```

Assuming the guess was correct, it will display the associated abbreviation.

Comment: 'z' and 'zz'  is depreciated now. how do we get the timezone in short format

Comment: @mperle - You can still use them, but only with moment-timezone.

Comment: how to get timezone using abbreviation. like  "  var mTimeZone = moment.tz("IST"); " insted of  "  var mTimeZone = moment.tz("Asia/Kolkata"); "

Comment: @PK-1825 - That would assume that IST only has one interpretation.  In fact, Ireland, Israel, and India all use the abbreviation `IST`.  Thus, such a function would be impossible to create.

Answer (score 5):

From the latest [moment timezone docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

```
moment.tz(String).format("Z z"); // -08:00 PST
moment.tz(String).zoneAbbr();    // PST
moment.tz(String).zoneName();    // PST
```

Some examples:

```
moment.tz(moment.tz.guess()).zoneAbbr(); // PST
moment.tz("America/New_York").zoneAbbr(); // EST
```

Answer (score 2):

**2020 Update**

Some time in the past 5 years, this stopped working. Now try:

```
var timeZone = moment.tz.guess();
var time = new Date();
var timeZoneOffset = time.getTimezoneOffset();
moment.tz.zone(timeZone).abbr(timeZoneOffset);
```

Answer (score 2):

After searching a lot, this seems to work.

```
const t = moment.tz.guess();
timeZone = moment.tz(t).zoneAbbr();;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not a good way, but I did not want to add any additional scripts in my project for local time zone, so I investigated a moment object and I get the local time zone by the code I wrote below:

```
 var test = momentUpdateDate._d.toString().substring(test.indexOf('(')+1, test.indexOf(')'));
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `_d`, but rather `.toDate()`, but still this isn't recommended as the output of `toString` is implementation specific and isn't guaranteed to be formatted in any particular way.  In practice, the time zone data is sometimes abbreviated, sometimes expanded, sometimes absent.

Answer (score 0):

My post is not just for this question but let me record a thing here.

Somehow `moment.tz.guess()` does not work in my environment. Using pure javascript `Intl` instead gave me the correct timezone.

```
const intl = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone // Asia/Tokyo
moment.tz(intl).zoneName() // JST
moment.tz(intl).zoneAbbr() // JST
```

fsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/qoozy/9xajy84b/20/