# How to get local date with Timezone(EDT/PST) in Angular JS using moment?

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I want the current local(to browser) date with Time zone in the following format:

```
26-Apr-2016 15:56:18 EDT
```

I have tried using moment.js but it shows date with timezone like GMT -04:00. Also tried this, but it didn't help.

```
  var dateDDMMMYYYYFormate = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'dd-MMM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss');
  var dateWithUtc = moment.utc(dateDDMMMYYYYFormate);
  var localDate = moment(dateWithUtc).local();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Moment.js to display the users local zone abbreviation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174807/using-moment-js-to-display-the-users-local-zone-abbreviation)

Answer (score 0):

Since [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) creates a JavaScript date object, you want to [change the moment object into a date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987647/moment-js-transform-to-date-object):

```
var localDate = moment().toDate();
```