# What is a good way to localize Timezone abbreviations, when there is only one locale that needs a translation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

According to [Does moment library support translation of time zone abbreviations like EST, IST etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603230/does-moment-library-support-translation-of-time-zone-abbreviations-like-est-ist), the only Timezone abbreviations that need to be translated are the following:

```
en_US
------------------------------------
PST = Pacific Standard Time
PDT = Pacific Daylight Time
MST = Mountain Standard Time
MDT = Mountain Daylight Time
CST = Central Standard Time
CDT = Central Daylight Time
EST = Eastern Standard Time
EDT = Eastern Daylight Time

fr_CA
------------------------------------
HNP = heure normale du Pacifique
HAP = heure avancée du Pacifique
HNR = heure normale des Rocheuses
HAR = heure avancée des Rocheuses
HNC = heure normale du Centre
HAC = heure avancée du Centre
HNE = heure normale de l’Est
HAE = heure avancée de l’Est
```

In addition, they only need to be translated to fr_CA. We currently use time format:

```
'%-d %b %Y %H:%M %Z'
```

Which emits the Timezone abbreviation as PDT (for example).

What is a good way to localize abbreviations for a single locale?

Comment: I think perhaps you misunderstood me in the other post. I wasn't stating that one needs to translate those.  I was just saying that I've never seen any abbreviations for time zones in any language other than English, or those ones in French.  Generally speaking, I don't believe time zone abbreviations have much value.  They are just too ambiguous and poorly defined.

Comment: I see. Our translator suggested translating them, but I don't know if they live in French Canada and speak French. I guess it's a good question for https://french.stackexchange.com/ or another Stack Exchange site. If that doesn't work, then I guess the only other option is to ask someone who lives in and speaks Canadian French.

Comment: Would love to know more about that myself.  Please share what you learn! :)

Comment: @MattJohnson - According to https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32195/18179, they are translations for 14 timezones to Canadian French.