# How to convert a string into timestamp, with moment js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, datetime-format, moment-timezone

I have the string "**18/04/19 5:17 PM EDT**" which represents a date.
I'm using [*moment* and the add-on *moment-timezone*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) and I need to convert this sting into a timestamp.

I'm trying something as:

```
var date = moment("18/04/19 5:17 PM EDT").format('DD/MM/YY h:m a z');
alert(date);
```

But this is not working and saying "invalid date".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, we then check if the string matches the [RFC 2822 Date time](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) format before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.

**Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings [is inconsistent](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.

> 

For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

so you are getting `Invalid Date` because your input is neither in ISO 8601 nor RFC 2822 recognized format, then you have to provide format parameter when parsing it.

[`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) does not accept `'z'` token, so you have to use moment-timezone to parse your input using zone, see [Parsing in Zone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) docs:

> The `moment.tz` constructor takes all the same arguments as the moment constructor, but uses the last argument as a [time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

You can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) and other methods listed in the [Displaying](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) section of the docs (e.g. [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/)) to display the value of a moment object.

Here a live sample:

```js
var date = moment.tz("18/04/19 5:17 PM EDT", 'DD/MM/YY h:m A', 'America/New_York');
console.log(date.valueOf()); // 1555622220000
console.log(date.format());  // 2019-04-18T17:17:00-04:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

As a side note, remeber that time zone abbreviations are ambiguous, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43603230/4131048) for additional info.