# IE11 Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString options timeZoneName support?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, timezone

Looking to use `Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString` to format `Date` objects, like this:

`new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en', {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit', timeZoneName: 'short'})`

In Chrome and Firefox, I get results like this:

Chrome: `"3:18:34 PM EDT"`

Firefox: `"3:19:17 PM EDT"`

However, in IE, I get results like this:

IE11: `"03:19:54 PM"` Notice the lack of "EDT".

I see [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#Browser_compatibility) that IE11 supposedly has full support of the `options` argument for this function. Am I missing something, or is there really no way to get the locale formatted string to include the time zone name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full compatibility matrix is [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esintl/), and looks like this presently:

[image: ECMAScript Intl Compatibility Table]

The two red boxes show that IE11 does not have such support.

Personally, I don't think it's likely that it ever will.  If you need to support IE11, you'll have to bring your own data for this via a library.  [Moment-Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) is one such library, and there is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24563710/634824) on how to use it in this capacity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Matt. I should have looked for a more granular breakdown of the support like you included. I tend to agree that I doubt IE11 will ever have this supported natively at this point. Thanks for the recommendation on Moment-Timezone, I will take a look.

Comment: How's the locale support for using Moment-Timezone for displaying a Date's time with timezone?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking, but moment has extensive locale support on it's own.   Time zone abbreviations are sourced from the IANA tzdb, pulled in via moment-timezone.

Comment: I was mostly asking about when formatting a date using moment-timezone, including the timezone via 'z', does the locale support provided by moment include proper translation of the timezone itself? i.e. EDT in english to whatever it may be in other languages? I'm not even sure if such pieces of information are translated.

Comment: No.  There is no reliable source of such data.  Time zone abbreviations are a pain - they mostly exist in English.  A few random French abbreviations exist, but are seldom used.  But also, many time zones don't have the concept of an abbreviation, so you'll just get a numeric offset instead.  Also, even when they do exist - nobody can agree on them definitively.  Example - is Hawaii HST or HAST?  Depends who you ask.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the insight. Sounds like my bases should be covered then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to do it in IE 11 then you can try to refer work around below.

It is not in short format.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the time as a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var rightNow = new Date();
    var TZ= String(String(rightNow).split("(")[1]).split(")")[0];
    var n = d.toLocaleTimeString('en', {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'});
 n += ' ' + TZ;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;



}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I have a requirement to display the timezone in short format, so this won't quite do the job.